# When should I run a PCA analysis to classify satelite images?

Tags: classification, landsat

I want to classify (using training data) some LANDSAT 8 OLI images.
I've come across some mentions of PCA analyses to avoid band-to-band correlations.
In what cases should one run a PCA? What is the advantage of doing so?

Comment: What algorithm are you planning on using for the classification or clustering (eg., supervised maximum likelihood, unsupervised isocluster, ...)? The dimensionality of Landsat is not very high and I have never really found it necessary to perform data reduction on this sensor. However, if the landscape is very homogeneous you can simplify things using PCA. Where it becomes more necessary is in hyperspectral data, where there is high correlation between bands due to narrow spectral ranges. With certain classification or clustering approaches, it is completely unnecessary.

Comment: I thought of using the random forest algorithm! How do I know if it's necessary to be run on my scenes or not? I have also read that most people use a Tasseled-cap transformation for LANDSAT images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the first thing to do would take a look at the Natural Color view of the imagery you are planning to classify - for Landsat 8, this would be arranging bands 4 as red, band 3 as green, and band 2 as blue.  You could then get a good sense of the overall quality of the data (that is, how bad effects like atmospheric distortion, "striping" which is present in some satellite image collections, cloud cover, and other types of haze/distortion might be).

Principal Component Analysis is generally used to correct for decorrelation caused by atmospheric noise or striping - if these are not present, I would proceed to a Supervised Classification based on your training data/vector inputs.  There may, however, be noise not visible in the red green blue bands, and if you have software that supports the process it wouldn't hurt to run it through a PCA.  But for most quality Landsat scenes, the returned component Eigen values (reported by the PCA) will be low and no action will be required.

If there is visible noise or striping (looks like washed-out lines diagonally across image layer), PCA can identify and then correct this after dropping the outlier Component from the bands, and outputting cleaned bands that you can then classify.  See pages 147-148 of Clark Labs Terrset Manual (a solid image processing application) for some more information on this, and before and after images:
https://clarklabs.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Terrset-Manual.pdf